# Tag merge / synonym request: [developer] -> [software-developer]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Tag merge / synonym request: [developer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developer) -> [software-developer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-developer)

It's possible they should both be added to STCI, but at the very least, I don't see much of a difference between these tags. Software developer has more questions and a wiki, so I suppose it should be the target.

[**Synonym link**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/software-developer/synonyms) for manual voting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purposes of being able to accept an answer:

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)